# Compare value in table by iterating table and select checkbox in front of that particular value

Tags: java, selenium, gradle, selenium-chromedriver, testng

Below is my code and its not showing any error on execution but not clicking on checkbox.
Listed all web elements in column and fetch the require title.

public void reviewProcessECL() {

```
    //to catch all web elements into list
    List<WebElement> myList=driver.findElements(By.xpath("//table/tbody/tr/td[5]"));

    //myList contains all the web elements
    //if you want to get all elements text into array list
    List<String> all_elements_text=new ArrayList<>();

    for(int i=0; i<myList.size(); i++) {

        all_elements_text.add(myList.get(i).getText());
        String id= myList.get(i).getText();

        if(id.contains(tdata.getProperty("Letter_Subject"))) {
            i++;    
            driver.findElement(By.xpath("//table/tbody/tr["+i+"]/td[11]")).click();
            driver.findElement(By.xpath("//table/tbody/tr["+i+"]/td[11]//div[@class='dropBox']//a[contains(text(),'Add Works')]")).click();

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you please share the HTML source of the <table>?

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this,

```
public void clickOnDropDown(String dropDownValue) {
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("yourXpath")).click();// click the dropdown

        List<WebElement> stroreValueFromDropDown = driver.findElements(By.xpath("yourXpath"));// store dropdown values

        for (WebElement list : stroreValueFromDropDown) { //iterate through the dropdown
            String listValue = list.getText();// get text
            if (listValue.contains(dropDownValue)) {// compare dropdown and expected text
                list.click();// click when expected value is found 
                break;
            }

        }

    }
```